# iOS - SKProductsResponse returns empty products array

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

My iOS app has in app purchases and all of them are set up correctly (they are waiting for review and my app is waiting for upload). But on some devices, some times, SKProductsResponse returns empty products array. And sometimes it doesn't, and the purchase process goes as expected..

It is inconsistent!

I have made all the checks listed here
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

but it didn't help

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this answer was of use to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817130/following-in-app-purchase-app-crashing-on-startup-productidentifier-nil/20027483#20027483

Comment: I am facing the same problem since some weeks. It worked fine for months though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be iOS issue and many people are facing this. Please see this question for details.
[Following in app purchase, app crashing on startup. productIdentifier=nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817130/following-in-app-purchase-app-crashing-on-startup-productidentifier-nil/20027483#20027483)