# iPhone not completing in-app transaction properly (IOS7)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, in-app-purchase

I hope someone can help here, I have two iPhone apps out in the store with in-app purchases. Both apps are mature code (been released for over 2 years) and both talk to the same web service and have been working fine for 2 years.

Now, we are getting a problem where some users (1 in 100, which is high for us) are completing the purchas and the devices just arent calling back to our web service after a successful transaction.

The process flow we have is

User Starts Transaction and requests payment for an item

User Enters their details for iTunes and the purchase succeeds (we see a valid payment in their iTunes account)

The App "should" then send the payment receipt to our web server to be validated and the app given permission to download the content

This process has been working fine for anything < IOS7 but for a few users since IOS7 we are not getting the call to our web server.

I am handling the transactionState of the SKPaymentTransaction correctly as it has been working for a long time, but as far as I can tell this method just isn't being hit sometimes?

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Thank You.

Comment: Yea this is a iOS7 bug. It's really annoying. I have some sort of a similar issue where my IAP was working perfectly fine while tested in sandbox mode, but when it's live. It's really temperamental. I have submitted a support to Apple, will keep you up to date as to what they say.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar issue with mature code. It appears that the app store is sending null productIdentifiers to the SKPaymentTransactionObserver under certain circumstances.

Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce in sandbox but I was able to with the App Store build.

- I removed my credit card from my Apple ID
- Then tried to purchase    in-app purchase
- Added my card info back in when prompted
- Went back to app

The app crashes on any subsequent launches as well because store kit tries to process the transaction on launch (with the null ID). It's easy enough to defensively code against the null product identifier but unfortunately it is going to require an update.

[This Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817130/following-in-app-purchase-app-crashing-on-startup-productidentifier-nil) was helpful.

Sorry this doesn't answer your question but hopefully you find the info useful.